# ajax jquery call rest webservice not working in mobile but work in desktop

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest

i call a **rest** web service with **ajax** **jquery** it work 's in desktop but when i call it with **mobile** it doesn't work . this is my code **ajax**

```
var result = function() {
    var tmp = null;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://41.12.222.23:8080/TESTWS/rest/p/image',
        success: function(data) {
            tmp = data.toString();
        }
    });
    return tmp;
}();
```

i have a table contains url of images tab=['41.12.222.23.:8080/folder/img1','41.12.222.23.:8080/fo‌​lder/img2'] this work perfectly in desktop and mobile but when a fill the table whith ajax rest service it work only in desktop

Comment: localhost may be the cause

Comment: `localhost` will be the cause. You need to place your code on a server accessible to all the devices you want to test with. Also, you should remove `async: false` as it's horrendous practice to use. Use a proper asynchronous code pattern instead.

Comment: url: 'http://41.12.222.23.:8080/TESTWS/rest/p/image'  im not using localhost

Comment: @Abdelilahsidiali type '41.12.222.23.:8080/TESTWS/rest/p/image' URL in mobile browser and try to access and let us know

Comment: it show nothing

Comment: what it show in desktop?

Comment: in desktop it show data

Comment: no i don t understand

Answer (score 1):

replace the 41 url with known image URL like this.

https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png 
and try it in mobile. Then you can verify your code.

I think your IP is not accessible in mobile network(LAN).

Comment: look i have a table contains  url of images tab=['41.12.222.23.:8080/folder/img1','41.12.222.23.:8080/folder/img2']  this work perfectly in desktop and mobile but when a fill the table whith ajax rest service it work only in desktop